# Recommended ownership of ~/public_html for apache?

Tags: permissions, apache2, ownership

Variations of this have been asked and answered here before, but I'm more after best practice from the options I list.

I'm running Apache and want to allow use of ~/public_html - but I'm wondering a bit about correct/best ownership of public_html.  As I see it, I got the following options:

- myuser:myuser, but adding access for the www-data user and/or group with ACL.
- myuser:www-data
- www-data:www-data and...

  - adding myuser to the www-data group.
  - adding access for the myuser user with ACL.

The obvious drawback with the 3rd option is obvious that I'm not owner of the directory, and must relay on root.  (OK, root is myself in this case, but the principle of the thing...)

I suppose I also should use `chmod g+s public_html` (or similar for ACL) so group-ownership gets inherited by sub-dirs.

So which is the recommended/default option?  Will another serve me better?

Comment: This question seems better suited to Apache forums. It has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Some of the questions that come immediately to mind are: (1) Do you use source control? (2) How many people have access to the web server? (3) How are files being put on the server now? (FTP, etc.) (4) If your web server were to be shut down due to hardware failure or other event, how painful would it be to rebuild your site? | Depending on the answer to these questions, there are a couple of options available that may drastically simplify your deployment methodology 

Answer (score 0):

- `public_html` should be owned by the user whose home directory it is in, and should be at least world searchable, or alternately, group www-data and group searchable (and g+s is not a bad idea, but the user won't be able to set either of those without help).
- Home directories should be world searchable, and subdirectories should not be if they are meant to be private.  But people can't remember to fix subdirectory permissions, so the default has been changed to make home directories not world searchable.  This is a compromise and can be adjusted by the user, or you can use an ACL to at least give www-data access to the home directory so the webserver can get to public_html.  There are other things typically in users' home directories that are meant to be published, so making the home directory private breaks these.
- If the user isn't in group www-data (and probably shouldn't be) then this permission is fragile along with the ACL.  This means the user can accidentally remove this permission and not be able to put it back.

Unfortunately, there are good reasons for each of these conflicting strategies, so there is no single good solution that covers all situations.